# Interactive Brokers Python Multiple Symbol Request

Tags: python, pandas, api, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I was able to piece together a script from IB's documentation/examples and forums on this site.  I am getting the output I want for a single symbol, however, if I use a list of stocks, I cannot figure out a way to pass the ticker symbol through to the DF output file.  My workaround was to create a dictionary that uses the list sequence (see below) however the output from IB's api changes slightly each time rendering the symbols mostly pointless.  The list i am using below normally has 20+ names but may change, i cut it down to make it easier to view.

@Brian/and or other developers, if there is a way to create either a unique ID/sequence for each symbol call and stamp it to data that is brought back, i can then utilize a dictionary to apply the symbol.  In the other forum, you passed in a line where n_id = n_id +1, if that can be applied and is linked to each specific call which is done in order of the list, then that could work?

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = [] #Initialize variable to store candle

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        #print(f'Time: {bar.date} Close: {bar.close} Volume: {bar.volume}',reqId)
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.close, bar.volume, reqId])
     
def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

symbols = ['SPY','MSFT','GOOG','AAPL','QQQ','IWM','TSLA']

for sym in symbols:
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = str(sym) 
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    #contract.primaryExchange = "ISLAND"
    app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, "", "1 D", "10 mins", "ADJUSTED_LAST", 1, 2, False, [])

 time.sleep(5) #sleep to allow enough time for data to be returned

df = pd.DataFrame(app.data, columns=['DateTime', 'ADJUSTED_LAST','Volume','reqId'])
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],unit='s') #,unit='s') 

df['Count'] = df.groupby('DateTime').cumcount()+1
sym_dict = {1:'SPY',2:'MSFT',3:'GOOG',4:'AAPL',5:'QQQ',6:'IWM',7:'TSLA'}

df['Ticker'] = df['Count'].map(sym_dict)

print(df)
```

#edit, adding in @Brian's detail:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = [] 

def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
    print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
    self.data.append([bar.date, bar.close, bar.volume, sym_dict[reqId]])
    print("HistoricalData. ReqId:", sym_dict[reqId], "BarData.", bar)
 
# include this callback to track progress and maybe disconnectwhen all are finished
def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
    print("finished", sym_dict[reqId])

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 123)

# you should wait for nextValidId instead of sleeping, what if it takes more than 1 second? @john: how do i do this?
time.sleep(5) @john: how do i do this? wait for nextValidId?

symbols = ['SPY','MSFT','GOOG','AAPL','QQQ','IWM','TSLA']

reqId = 1
sym_dict = {}
for sym in symbols:
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = str(sym) 
    sym_dict[reqId] = sym
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    #contract.primaryExchange = "ISLAND" # you may need this for msft
    app.reqHistoricalData(reqId, contract, "", "1 D", "10 mins", "ADJUSTED_LAST", 1, 2, False, [])
    reqId += 1
    time.sleep(5)

df = pd.DataFrame(app.data, columns=['DateTime', 'ADJUSTED_LAST','Volume','sym'])
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],unit='s') #,unit='s') 
df = df.set_index(['sym','DateTime']).sort_index()
print(df)
app.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to maintain a dict of reqId and symbol.

I'm not sure that one DataFrame is the best way to store your data but if you do then set a multi index.  Decide how much data you want and how you're going to store it on disk and then decide on a data structure.  I suggest csv for speed or sqlite for simplicity.  Pandas can handle either.

I deleted your comments and added some of my own.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

# I added this code to get fake data, works wtihout tws running
from ibapi.common import BarData
from random import random
start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
def fake_data(reqId, ib):
    last = reqId*10
    for i in range(60, 0, -10):
        bar = BarData();
        bar.date = start - timedelta(minutes=i)
        last += random() - 0.5
        bar.close = last
        bar.volume = reqId * 1000
        ib.historicalData(reqId, bar)
    ib.historicalDataEnd(reqId,"","")
    
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = [] 

    #always include this for important messages, also turn on api logging in TWS/IBG    
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.close, bar.volume, sym_dict[reqId]])
     
    # include this callback to track progress and maybe disconnectwhen all are finished
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        print("finished", sym_dict[reqId])
        
def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 123)

# threading is needed only if you plan to interact after run is called
# this is a good way if you use a ui like jupyter
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

# you should wait for nextValidId instead of sleeping, what if it takes more than 1 second?
time.sleep(1)

symbols = ['SPY','MSFT','GOOG','AAPL','QQQ','IWM','TSLA']

reqId = 1
sym_dict = {}
for sym in symbols:
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = str(sym) 
    sym_dict[reqId] = sym
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    #contract.primaryExchange = "ISLAND" # you may need this for msft
    #app.reqHistoricalData(reqId, contract, "", "1 D", "10 mins", "ADJUSTED_LAST", 1, 2, False, [])
    fake_data(reqId, app)
    reqId += 1
    #now you need to sleep(10) to make sure you don't get a pacing error for too many requests
    
# don't sleep, use historicalDataEnd to know when finished
time.sleep(5)

df = pd.DataFrame(app.data, columns=['DateTime', 'ADJUSTED_LAST','Volume','sym'])
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],unit='s')

#make an index and sort
df = df.set_index(['sym','DateTime']).sort_index()
# now you can use the indexes
print(df.loc[("SPY","2021")])

#don't forget to disconnect somewhere or the clientId will still be in use
```

Comment: thank you so much for reviewing!  This is incredibly helpful, however, i think i am missing something when applying your response to actual historical data.  The random data for testing that you applied is very cool and i will definitely use that for other endeavors.  I am going to add what i attempted to apply, as i am missing something simple in the translation

Comment: It's possible I made a mistake.  I just don't have TWS at my location for a while.  Just use your historical data request instead of the fake data.

Comment: Awesome!  No worries- I appreciate the help so much- I will eventually get it to work!  My background is trading and not dev work!  I am all about finding the 2k ways that a light bulb doesn’t work haha.  Per your inquiry before- my intention is to apply the output through some pandas analysis and then send them back to me as signals in either an email or slack notification- thanks again for your help!!